# http  POST error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, http-post

I'm trying to send the xml to another webserver through Restclient's http POST request.This is the code :

```
response =  RestClient.post 'https://secure.rowebooks.co.uk/testorders/orders.aspx', :content_type => "text/xml", :myfile => File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/shared/#{@book}.xml")
```

But I'm getting this error

```
ERROR 2 Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.ERROR3 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I've been told that I am receiving that error because the XML file is not in the content of the call. It must be in the content. I have no idea what does this mean.

Any suggestion / clue will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing it like this:

```
response =  RestClient.post( 'https://secure.rowebooks.co.uk/testorders/orders.aspx', 
File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/shared/#{@book}.xml"), 'Content-Type' => 'text/xml' )
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply but the code you posted returns error - "syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC". Is there anything missing?